# Ender 3 - Are my 2040 Z extrusions bent?

Tags: creality-ender-3, mechanics

While installing my dual Z rod kit for my Ender 3, I noticed something I had completely missed. From the looks of it, I think my Z 2040 extrusions are bent? When I look at the printer head-on at the bottom the Z extrusion sits flush with the Y extrusion shown below:

[image: Bottom view of Z Extrusion]

However, when I then look at it head-on at the top, the Z extrusion does not sit flush with the 2020 extrusion mounted on top shown below:

[image: Top view of Z Extrusion]

This is the case for both Z 2040 extrusions. Does this mean my extrusions are bent? How would this affect my prints? Would I need to buy replacement 2040 extrusions or is this fine?

Comment: I would not assume the top 2020 crossbar is cut to the exact length; mine seems to be slightly longer too. What matters is that the distance between the two 2040 Z extrusions is constant along their length. Do you have a way to assess that?

Comment: One thing to check: If the Z extrusions were significantly bent, I would expect the V slot rollers not to grip consistently. For example you might have one Z height where the inner wheels are tight but the outer ones are loose, and another height where the outer ones are tight but the inner ones are loose.

Comment: So I measured the distance between the two extrusions at the top and bottom. At the bottom, it came out to ~120.85mm, and at the top, it came out to ~120.95mm. Is that within margin of error? Along with that, when the x gantry is at the bottom, on the right extrusion, the inner wheel feels fine, the outer bottom wheel is fine, the outer top wheel is slightly looser but still feels okay. However, when the x gantry is moved to the top of the Z extrusion, the outer top wheel can be freely moved with my fingers, but the outer bottom and inner wheels feel fine.